# How do I get a date from Spanish string in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following string

`21 de julio de 2019`

Which I want to parse to a useable DateTime instance.

I've tried variations of the following.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d * M * Y", '21 de julio de 2019');

//Setting Locale
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d * M * Y", '21 de julio de 2019');
```

But `$date` is always `false`.

### Based off of the answer

```
$dateString = '21 de julio de 2019';
echo 'Given date is ' . $dateString . "\n";

//Given date is 21 de julio de 2019

$tz = IntlTimeZone::createTimeZone('Europe/Madrid');
echo 'Tz is ' . $tz->getId() . "\n";

//Tz is Europe/Madrid

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'es_ES',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    $tz->getId(),
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    "d * M * Y");

$parsedDate = $formatter->parse($dateString);

$date = new DateTime($parsedDate);

echo 'Parsed date '. $date->format('d-m-Y');

//Parsed date 25-07-2019
```

Not quite as nearly there as I thought :/ turns out `$parsedDate` is empty, so `new DateTime($parsedDate)` is today.

Comment: Use IntlDateFormatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So PHP cannot handle foreign language strings as input to parse, only when outputting dates will it use localised string values.

The solution then was to utilise a third party library,

https://github.com/jenssegers/date

> Methods such as parse and createFromFormat also support "reverse translations". When calling these methods with translated input, it will try to translate it to English before passing it to DateTime:

`$date = Date::createFromFormat('l d F Y', 'zaterdag 21 maart 2015');`

Or in my case

`$date = Date::createFromFormat('d * M * Y', '21 de julio de 2019');`

Answer (score 2):

Try using IntlDateFormatter:

```
$dateString = '21 de julio de 2019';
echo 'Given date is '.$dateString;
$tz = reset(iterator_to_array(IntlTimeZone::createEnumeration('ES')));
$formatter = datefmt_create(
    'es_ES',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    $tz,
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN);
echo 'Formatter '.$formatter;
$parsedDate=datefmt_format.format($formatter, $dateString);
echo 'Parsed date '.$parsedDate;
```

Comment: can you expand on the `reset(iterator_to_array...` bit please. Where you are determining the timezone.

Comment: If you know the timezone Id use it as IntlTimeZone::createTimeZone($id) otherwise get the enumeration of all time zone Ids by country code.

Comment: Struggling to get this to output the parsed date.

Comment: I've updated my question to show what I'm doing based off your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the names of the months are written correctly you may replace them and then generate a timestamp.

```
$dateString = '21 de julio de 2019'; // Your input.

$months = [
1 => 'enero',
2 => 'febrero',
3 => 'marzo',
4 => 'abril',
5 => 'mayo',
6 => 'junio',
7 => 'julio',
8 => 'agosto',
9 => 'septiembre',
10 => 'octubre',
11 => 'noviembre',
12 => 'diciembre',
];

$dateString = strtolower($dateString); // Just to be sure that you'll compare lower case strings.
$dateString = str_replace($months, array_keys($months), $dateString); // Replace the month names with numbers.
$dateString = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/i", ".", $dateString); // Replace all non digit chars with slashes.

$timestamp = strtotime($dateString); // Get a timestamp. You can use it whith a class of your choice.

echo date('d * M * Y', $timestamp); // Output.
```

Comment: This does answer the question, but I don't think it is the best solution.

Comment: The best solution depends on your needs but this one will not depend on any specific library (it's portable).

Comment: My needs may well move beyond Spanish once I've got it solved, so would have to maintain several lists of `$months` arrays

Comment: If you're able to use `setlocale()` on your servers you may auto translate via `strftime()`